# Java Swing Application in a web

Tags: java, html, swing, deployment

I'm doing a portfolio with projects I've made and I have some Java Swing projects. I'm not sure about which is the best way of showing them in my web. I've tried to export them to jar and embed in the html but it doesn't work. Is there any other posibilities?

Comment: *"I'm doing a portfolio with projects I've made and I have some Java Swing projects. I'm not sure about which is the best way of showing them in my web."*  Github.  Or ..sourceforge, or.. wherever you can upload the code.  People who would view the projects as part of a portfolio would most likely prefer to see a (screenshot and) **the code.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an **Applet** to show your Swing project.

Or you can use **Webstart** to launch your applicatoin via a website. The Webstart option display the application complete in its own frame. There is nothing embedded in the HTML.

Comment: I'd recommend either Webstart, and/or simply provide the jar for download.

Comment: The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  They can be deployed from a link on a web page.  Forget applets, seriously.  They've had major problems with browsers blocking them, and Chrome is soon to remove all support for them.

Comment: Yep.  Really.  As well as anything else that requires NPAPI.  See [Oracle's take on the matter](https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml).  Their suggestion seems to boil down to *'use another browser'* which reads here like *'f_ck it, we give up!'*.

Comment: Java Web Start also requires NPAPI, which is what Chrome is going to stop supporting. I'd love to see a robust answer to this question that does not involve applets or JWS, which will continue working cross-browser including Chrome.